# Regular expression to format datetime format using python

Tags: python, string

I have an invalid json list and would like to change the "'at' : datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 15, 57, 48)" to "'at' : '2020-07-04 15:47:41' " for all timestamp it the list.
Is it possible do with *re.sub*?

```
{
 'reviewId': '...', 
 'userName': '...', 
 'userImage': '...', 
 'content': '...', 
 'score': 1, 
 'thumbsUpCount': 0, 
 'reviewCreatedVersion': 
 '2.0.1-rc1', 
 'at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 15, 57, 48), 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/LQePta/1) help? You can get  the group 1 and then split on `,` and join on `:`

Answer (score 1):

This code should work

```
import datetime

json = {
 'reviewId': '...', 
 'userName': '...', 
 'userImage': '...', 
 'content': '...', 
 'score': 1, 
 'thumbsUpCount': 0, 
 'reviewCreatedVersion': 
 '2.0.1-rc1', 
 'at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 15, 57, 48)
}

json['at'] = json['at'].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(json)
```

If your json is an array of obj, just do a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could brute force it by matching groups and zero-filling the results out to the required width:

```
import re

s = "... 'at': datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 4, 15, 57, 48) ..."
o = re.sub(r"'at'\s*:\s*datetime.datetime\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)",
           lambda m:"'at':'" + m.group(1) + "-" + m.group(2).zfill(2) + "-" + m.group(3).zfill(2) + " " + m.group(4).zfill(2) + ":" + m.group(5).zfill(2) + ":" + m.group(2).zfill(2) + "'",
           s)
print(o)
```

Output:

```
... 'at':'2020-07-04 15:57:07' ...
```

Comment: @WhiteTopaz did I misunderstand your question? Is that not a JSON string?